# how to style tab bar icon alloy tatanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How to style the icons in the tab bar in tabbed view project. 
because when i put a *.png icons , the icons appear as gray in inactive tabs , and blue in the active tab, how to display it as it is.

```
<Tab title="Tab 1" icon="setting.png">
     <Window title="Tab 1">
       <Label>I am Window 1</Label>
     </Window>
   </Tab>
```

and how to add fonts icons to the tab icons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mahmoud gamal Well, there's no a good way to style the ***tab bar*** in ***Titanium***, it's hard to change the system-default-style of tab bar. The problem you had mentioned that the **inactive tab** will be grey and the **active tab** will be blue, well this the system style of the tab bar, you can [check here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Tab) for more details.

However, you can set property ***activeIcon*** of tab bar to change it's active state style, but it's only support for **IOS**. If you want to get the tab bar more various style, we recommend you just define a ***view*** like the tab bar to accomplish what you want. And, pay attention to this that the **tab embed with window will display at different position in Android(show at the top of he window) and IOS(show at the bottom at the window)**.